# Google Developer Console. В настоящий момент через это приложение контент не продается.

Tags: java, android

я хочу добавить Внутренние Платежи (in app billing) в приложение. В документации google написано что нужно добавить permission `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.venging.BILLING"/>` в manifest файл. Я добавил это разрешение  и IInAppBillingService.aidl в проект, настроил работу с сервисом. Но в консоли разработчика написано 
*"В настоящий момент через это приложение контент не продается. 
Чтобы загружать контент для продажи через приложения, добавьте в APK-файл разрешение BILLING."*.
 У кого нибудь была такая проблема? Нужно ли ждать пока google обновит информацию?

Comment: Да, скорее всего надо чтобы приложение обновилось в маркете. Обычно 3-5 часов это занимает.

Comment: Приложение в маркете уже обновилось, но добавить платеж все равно не получается

Comment: Хм... Боясь показаться занудным всё же уточню - версия одна и та же на девайсе и в маркете? Подписаны обе релизным ключом? Акк не девелопер и прописан в бета-тестерах? Кэш приложения-маркета почищен? Кэш приложения самого почищен? Вроде все условия...

Comment: У меня ошибка в самом permission. Вместо vending я написал venging по невнимательности

Comment: Если после этого всё заработало - напишите это в ответ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение: У меня ошибка в самом permission. Вместо vending я написал venging по невнимательности.